# PHP PayPal simple API, one time payment

Tags: php

I have this code to setup recurring payments on PayPal

```
$p->add_field('cmd','_xclick-subscriptions');
$p->add_field('business','payments@pitchmystuff.com');
$p->add_field('item_name', 'Remove Album Release');
$p->add_field('return', $this_script.'?action=success&idAlbum='.$idAlbum.'&package='.$package);
$p->add_field('cancel_return', $this_script.'?action=cancel&idAlbum='.$idAlbum);
$p->add_field('notify_url', 'http://pitchmystuff.com/modules/yobilab/digidist/PayPal/paypal_remove.php');
$p->add_field('no_note','1');
$p->add_field('currency_code','USD');
$p->add_field('a3', "$paymentAmount");
$p->add_field('t3', "Y");
$p->add_field('p3', "1");
$p->add_field('src', "1");
$p->add_field('sra', "1");
```

How do I change it to work with ONE TIME payments and NOT recurring?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change `$p->add_field('cmd','_xclick-subscriptions');` to `$p->add_field('cmd','_xclick');` to enable one time payments.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: I haven't used the subscription / recurring payments API before, so bear that in mind when reading my answer as there may be a way to do this with the API you are using that I don't know about.**

For one time payments you might try using the adaptive payments API or the express checkout API instead, docs for express checkout API are here:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted

And docs for adaptive payments API:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro

(another note - paypal has been moving everything to x.com but managed to somehow lose alot of their docs, so they are kinda spread over two sites. Also, x.com is bad.)

Hope this helps

EDIT: at a guess, your 'cmd' param needs changed. Not sure what you should change it TO, however.

Answer (score 0):

Set p3 to 0 (p3 - number of time periods between each recurrence)